# Should 2 different tables share the same like/vote table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm in a situation where I'm in a bit of doubt of whenever I should give a shared 'like' table or split it up into two different tables.

The application will show both videos/images in a 'wall' like manner, like Facebook and many other platforms do.

If the user has already liked an image or video the like button will be colored to show that the content has already been liked.

**Video table**

```
id    title    desc     url    src
------------------------------------
 1    soms     thing   wwww    .png
```

**Image table**

```
id    title    desc      src
------------------------------
 1    soms     thing    .jpg
```

**Options 1 two tables**

Vote table video

```
id    video_fk    user_fk    voted
-----------------------------------------
 1        1           1          2
```

Vote table image

```
id    image_fk    user_fk    voted
-----------------------------------------
 1        1           1          2
```

**Options 2 1 table**

Vote table shared (type_fk is identifying which type it is, 1 for image 2 for video)

```
id    content_fk    user_fk    type_fk    voted
-------------------------------------------------
 1        1           1          2          2
```

The problem with 2 tables is when I have to lookup whenever or not a user has liked the content (when scrolling through the wall with many results) I will have to store the results in a multidimensional array with the id and an identifier to decide which content type it is (image or video).

What would you be the better way, or even a third way?

Comment: I've given you answer, but I'll elaborate a bit more here.

If you pick my approach, meaning reducing both tables to `content` and `votes`, you could store content type inside the `content` table and thus remove it from `votes` as it's quite an antipattern, because you are storing info about content in a table designed to keep info about votes.

Comment: Regardless of which way you go, get rid of `id` since there is a "natural" `PRIMARY KEY` that is the 'composite' of 2 or 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep as little tables as possible, because then you reduce amount of requests and complexity of your code.

I would even go as far as to put both videos and images into the same table called 'content', seeing how almost all of your columns are the same.

Comment: I thought about that, but you see, there are more than just 2 content types, there are also articles + like 5 more and these tables are very simplified :)

But you would suggest 1 table for likes, this is also what I've thought would be the better solution, it really simplifies alot

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 If you have content like `articles`, `images`, `videos` perhaps `music` or so on. I would divide them into categories: `images`, `videos` and `music` being `media`, because effectively the only columns you would need for that would be `id`, `title`, `desc`, `type (enum)`, `url (but renamed to src)`, storing the file extension is obsolete if you know how to use MIME Type detection.

For other types of content, I would keep appropriate tables, unless they can be categorised as well.

Comment: that gave some food for thought, thanks for the help

Comment: I was going to add a comment about this as well - that you only have two types of content but this may extend in the future, and you dont want to have to keep adding new tables. I would definitely go with the single content table that includes a reference to content type.

Comment: If you have to reach back into Videos using `content_fk`, the code gets messy.

Comment: @RickJames Not really. He didn't say what technology he's using, but if he's using ORM then he definitely would have navigational properties.